# Get Test Instance Names from test set folder in Java using API

Tags: java, api, alm

I am trying to get the test instance names from the test set. I am able to get the test id by using the following URL:

```
"rest/domains/"+domain+"/projects/"+project+"/test-instances?query={cycle-id["+testSetId+"]}" ;
```

Is there any way I can get the test names also?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're talking about the ALM Rest API.
If you do, you can try to add in final of your URL the following:

`&fields=test-config.name`

Then your URL will look like this:

`rest/domains/{domain}/projects/{project}/test-instances?query={cycle-id[{testSetId}]}&fields=test-config.name`

The name of your Test Instance will be shown into the RelatedEntities tag from your XML.

For more information about ALM REST API you can [click here](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/DownloadHelpCenter_alm_12.50.htm).